# jquery: bind LOAD event after creating a iframe DOM object

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

How do I do this?

```
$('#divToInsert').html('<iframe id="outputPage" src="/Folder/webpage.aspx" width="90%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="overflow-x: hidden"><p>WARNING: Your browser does not support iframes. Please contact your adminstrator for assistance.</iframe>');
$('#outputPage').unbind('load');
$('#outputPage').bind('load', function() {
    alert('done!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo?

```
  // ---------v---------------there's a "t" that shouldn't be there
$('#outputPaget').bind('load',
```

Works for me after that correction.

Make sure the DOM is loaded too.

http://jsfiddle.net/gz2eS/

```
$(function() {
    $('#divToInsert').html('<iframe id="outputPage" src="/Folder/webpage.aspx" width="90%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="overflow-x: hidden"><p>WARNING: Your browser does not support iframes. Please contact your adminstrator for assistance.</iframe>');
    $('#outputPage').unbind('load');
    $('#outputPage').bind('load', function() {
        alert('done!');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Martin: Is the DOM loaded? I posted a jsFiddle example in my answer. Your code works. Make sure the `divToInsert` ID is correct too.

Comment: btw, it renders a pdf inside the page if that means something else.

Comment: @Martin: I'm not sure what the issue would be. Maybe try it with an HTML document instead of the PDF.